# Is it possible to use AWS EFS access points to mount a kubernetes persistent volume in EKS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks, amazon-efs

First of all to put some context on that question.

- I have an `EKS` cluster with version >= `1.15`
- The `EFS` - `EKS` `security group` / `mount target` etc. are working properly
- The `CSI` driver for `EFS` in `EKS` is installed and work as expected
- I have deployed a storage class called `efs-sc` using the `EFS CSI` driver as a provisioner
- I can access the `EFS` volume on the pod

But ... it only works if it is the root path `/` that is defined as the path in the `kubernetes` persistent volume resource definition.

**Example with Terraform 0.12 syntax**

```
resource "kubernetes_persistent_volume" "vol" {
  metadata {
    name = "my-vol"
  }
  spec {
    capacity = {
      storage = "15Gi"
    }
    access_modes = ["ReadWriteMany"]
    storage_class_name = "efs-sc"
    persistent_volume_reclaim_policy = "Recycle"
    persistent_volume_source {
      nfs {
        path = "/" # -> OK it works properly
        # path = "/access-point-path" -> NOT WORKING
        server = var.efs-storage-apt-server
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to specify the path of my access point the mounting of the volume fails.

The `efs` access point is configured like this

[image]

So is it a limitation? Did I miss something?

I was looking about this solution [efs-provisioner](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/tree/master/aws/efs) but I don't see what this will solve from this current configuration.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I'm on something similar: EKS is not able to mount the EFS volume when an access point is specified. It seems that it can not create the mount directory inside `/var/lib/kubelet/pods/<pod-id>/`

Answer (score 4):

There's now documentation available: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/blob/master/examples/kubernetes/access_points/README.md#create-access-points-in-efs

You'll need to be using the updated EFS CSI driver. The access point is defined under PersistentVolume's `volumeHandle`. The recent EFS CSI driver no longer supports dynamic binding, hence, the PersistentVolume needs to be created manually for each PersistentVolumeClaim.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: efs-pv1
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: efs-sc
  csi:
    driver: efs.csi.aws.com
    volumeHandle: [FileSystemId]::[AccessPointId]
```

Answer (score 1):

What seems to be happening is that the path `/access-point-path` does not exist inside your mounted filesystem.

When you use access points, the path specified by the access point is mounted as the `/` of the filesystem.

Let's suppose this is the state of your *EFS*:

```
|__ access-point-path/
```

When you mount it in your deployment using access point in `/access-point-path`, it only sees an empty folder, because the `access-point-path` folder is now the root directory (`/`) of your deployment. There is no `access-point-path` folder to bind.

That's why the `/` works and the `access-point-path/` does not.